# IllegalArgumentException when using joda-time to convert string to date

Tags: java, jodatime, string-to-datetime

I have a code as below to convert a string to date:

```
DateTimeFormatter formatter = org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat.forPattern("MM/dd/yyyy");
LocalDate checkInDate = LocalDate.parse("08/25/2015");
```

But when i run the code there is an error:

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid format: "08/25/2015" is malformed at "/25/2015"

Anyone can help me resolve this problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try using the formatter:

`LocalDate checkInDate = formatter.parseLocalDate("08/25/2015");`